# Is it possible to have a "dynamic" help text?

Tags: python, function

I can supply a help text like this:

```
def my_func(): 
    "help text"
```

such that `help(my_func)` will print `help text`.

Is it possible to construct that help string from a global variable?

For example this:

```
test = "123"

def my_func():
     "help text" + test
```

wont print anything for `help(my_func)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can override `__doc__` attribute

```
test = "123"

def my_func():
    pass

my_func.__doc__ = "help text" + test
```

From [PEP-0257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/):

> A docstring is a string literal that occurs as the first statement in a module, function, class, or method definition. Such a docstring becomes the `__doc__` special attribute of that object.